# How to add rule and add feature class to topology using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, topology, indentationerror

```
import arcpy
import os

# Set the workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\topology\Contours.gdb"
# The name of the data_set containing the topology
data_set = "Contours"
# The name of the topology
topology = "contour_topology"

# Rules for topology
topoRules = ["Must Not Self-Overlap (Line)", "Must Not Self-Intersect (Line)"]

# Get the fully qualified name/path of the topology
path_topology = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, data_set, topology)
# Get the feature classes within the specified dataset
feature_classes = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset = data_set)

# Check to make sure there are some feature classes
if feature_classes is not None:
    # for each feature class
    for fc in feature_classes:
        # Get the fully qualified path to the feature class
        path_fc = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, data_set, fc)
        print(path_fc)
        print(fc)

        # Try and add the feature class to the topology
        try:
            # add the feature class to the topology
            arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(path_topology, path_fc, 1, 1)
            # added the rules here
    arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(path_topology, topoRules[0], path_fc," ", " ", " ")
            arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(path_topology, topoRules[1], path_fc," ", " ", " ")
        except Exception as e:
            # print any errors we might get
            print(e)
```

I am getting error like:

> Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 31)

Comment: You have an indentation error on line 31.

Comment: how to rectify it?

Comment: Your arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management statement needs to be indented at the same level as the statement above and below it

Comment: @artwork21 iam not able to do it....little confused...can you please edit the code

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment noted, your arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management statement needs to be indented at the same level as the statement above and below it:

```
        try:
            # add the feature class to the topology
            arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(path_topology, path_fc, 1, 1)
            # added the rules here
            arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(path_topology, topoRules[0], path_fc," ", " ", " ")
            arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(path_topology, topoRules[1], path_fc," ", " ", " ")
        except Exception as e:
            # print any errors we might get
            print(e)
```

Comment: iam getting the following errors "ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The class is already a member of the topology.
Failed to execute (AddFeatureClassToTopology). "

Comment: does the rule already exist in the topology?